# Show amount Woocommerce completed orders within a specific months

Tags: woocommerce, state

I would like to have a view of the amount of orders that where put to a completed state within the last months. I do not need very much details but just a very simple list with two columns.

"Month" & "Amount of completed orders"

No further details are required. The only important point is that this list should just contain orders that are in the completed state. Furthermore, I do not care when the order was made, but I need to know by when the order was set to completed. So the timing of the status change is important for me.

Example: customer buys product in May, business owner set order manually to completed in June. Then this purchase should be visible as part of June and not May.

Any chance I can create such a query?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself:

SELECT Year(pm.meta_value), Month(pm.meta_value), Count(p.ID) FROM `wp_posts` p JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm on p.ID = pm.post_id where p.post_status = 'wc-completed' and p.post_type = "shop_order" and pm.meta_key = "_completed_date" group by DATE_FORMAT(pm.meta_value, '%Y-%mm') order by DATE_FORMAT(pm.meta_value, '%Y-%mM') DESC

Comment: You could format the solution using the available editing tools so that future readers will be able to understand it clearly.